# Maven parent project structure

Tags: maven

I have little doubt about project maven structuring

We need to have one common project and one parent project for each of

1. Services projects
2. Framework projects
3. DAO projects

The question here is

Can we combine three parent project into single project having separate folder for each project ? and

The structure will look Like

EnterpriseParent

-----Service
        --------pom.xml

-----Framework
        --------pom.xml

-----DAL
        --------pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible. It's called aggregation. you can achieve it by creating modules in your pom.

so you get structure like

```
pom.xml (parent pom)
  |
  |___ pom.xml (in framework dir)
  |
  |___ pom.xml (in service dir)
  |
  |___ pom.xml (in DAL dir)
```

Your parent pom will contain:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Master POM</name>
    <modules>
        <module>framework</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>dal</module>
    </modules>
    ...
</project>
```

And your child poms will have the following structure:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>your.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>framework/service/dal</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>SAL project</name>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Combining the aggregator and the parent in a single project is a bad idea: they serve different purposes. The aggregator only ensures all the project are built at the same time in a valid order, the parent provides a single definition point for definitions shared among the projects (e.g. versions of dependencies)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the idea here is EnterpriseParent project should have only parent pom no other code, but at the same time we want to have proper decoupling between services projects , framework projects and DAL projects .. the other thought is to have three separate project each for one but concern is the parent project will only have pom and creating a project for single pom is little not convincing to me, having separate project for each parent POM is good practice?

Comment: @Nicola, thanks for your comment, I find it useful since my parent pom can contain all dependencyManagement entries - I tried to keep the example as simple as it could be.

Comment: I use an additional POM type module as parent to the aggregator and all the other modules

Comment: Thank you Nicola and Miron,  Nicola i agree ,I have created 3 modules with pom packaging type, to have decoupling between service , framework and DAL thank you for the help.